# htaccess rewrite rule needed

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite rules to strip out a get parameter so the following URL:

```
http://www.showsec.co.uk/?css=stylesheets/dropkick
```

would become

```
http://www.showsec.co.uk/stylesheets/dropkick
```

Here is what I have tried that doesn't seem to work:

```
RewriteRule ^/?css=$ /$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+\?css=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^css= [NC]
RewriteRule ^(stylesheets/.+?)/?$ /?css=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: Glad to know it worked but What I'm surprised is that some gentleman down voted it without leaving any comment :P